# Как правильно передать интент из сервиса через broadcastReceiver в активити

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Я сначала делал приложение по видео уроку https://youtu.be/XM3THjZkRQM
Там о том как получать уведомления от GCM и показывать уведомления в трее. 
Приложение работает. Но у меня задача немного отличается от видео урока. 
С сервера в GCM отправляется сообщение, от GCM оно принимается сервисом, и вот дальше в сервисе надо вместо показа пуш уведомления в трее, отправить определённую команду в активити приложения (и в приложении будет много разных активити, так что надо, чтобы эту команду приняла та активити, которая в данный момент открыта).
Я решил начать с малого и попробовать сделать приём сообщения в MainActivity.
Там уже реализован BroadCastReceiver, который был в уроке. Но он был настроен на приём статуса регистрации в GCM.

Вот код главной активити:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReciever;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("INTENT",intent.getAction());
                if(intent.getAction().equals(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS)){
                    String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GCM token: "+token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(intent.getAction().equals(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_ERROR)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GCM registration error!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    //tobe define
                }
            }
        };

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS != resultCode){
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Google Play Service is not installed/enable in this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(resultCode,getApplicationContext());
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This device do not support Google Play Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else{
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,GCMRegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.w("Main Activity","onResume");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever,
                new IntentFilter(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever,
                new IntentFilter(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_ERROR));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.w("Main Activity","onPause");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever);
    }
}
```

А вот файл манифеста:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test3.gcmtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="test3.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="test3.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="test3.gcmtest"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMPushReceiverService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".GCMRegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Это сервис, который отвечает за приём сообщений от GCM и показ пушей:

```java
public class GCMPushReceiverService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String messageType = data.getString("messagetype");
        Log.w("MESSAGE_TYPE",messageType);
        if(messageType.equals("push")){
            Log.d("START","sender");
            Intent pushIntent=new Intent("pusher");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushIntent);
        }
        else {
            sendNotification(message);
        }

    }

    private void sendNotification(String message){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        int requestCode = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri sound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("My GCM message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,noBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

В нём мне надо обработать полученное сообщение и вытащить ключ, в котором будет тип сообщения. В одном случае должен сработать пуш в трее, а вдругом случае надо в главной активити запустить определённое действите (потом там надо будет в текстовом поле определённое значение менять)

Первый вопрос: правильно ли я отправляю интент?

```java
                Intent pushIntent=new Intent("pusher");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushIntent);
```

Второй вопрос: как правильно этот интент принять в MainActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока ждал ответа, сам разобрался))

Я не знаю почему до этого не получалось, но сделал так (В любой активити, не только в главной):

```java
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(GCMPushReceiverService.MESSAGE_SENDER));
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Действие, которое надо выполнить при получении сообщения:
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.d("receiver", "Got message: "+message);
            testTXT.setText(testTXT.getText()+"\n"+message);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Где GCMPushReceiverService.MESSAGE_SENDER это статическая текстовая константа, которая содержит имя пакета и произвольное название. Но я не думаю что её содержимое должно содержать название пакета.

Так же в решении вопроса помог этот источник: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html